# convert large form number to string from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that does a lookup on a DB2 tech_id. The tech_id is a 26 digit number. I want to pass this as a string via ajax to my backend process, but every time it gets converted:

`2.015052714252E+25`

which breaks the backend code.

I thought by using the `toString` function I'd get around this, but no luck. Here's the jquery part:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
var id = $('#tech_id').val().toString(); // the form input with the tech_id
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'do_stuff',
    data: {id: id}, // also tried data: {id: id.toString()} here
    dataType: 'json',
    encode: true
})
```

Then in the backend I pass it in like this, again attempting to cast as a string:

```
    $techid = $content['id']; // from the PHP $_POST array
    $host = 'my_API_endpoint'; 

    $url = $host."/user/".$techid;

    $results = file_get_contents((string) $url);
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
file_get_contents(http:my_api_endpoint/user/2.015052714252E+25): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP\/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
```

Any idea what's the problem?

EDIT: I've narrowed it down to the form handler in the controller, which automatically `json_decodes` all inputs. It's the `json_decode` function (in php) that is converting the string.

Comment: Show us `var_dump($_POST)` and also how that value gets from `$_POST` to `$content`.

Comment: Yeah, cause I've tried your code and it works for me.

Comment: add eval function when setting value to tech_id means it will print all digits

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have BigInteger type, so it converts to exponent form. Basically to handle such type of cases people use so many techniques.

There are so many libraries as well to handle this. like [BigInt](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html), [BigNumber](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber) etc.,

But for your case, as I understood, I would suggest to try converting the 26 digit number to hexadecimal and send it to backend. In backend again convert it back to Integer from hexadecimal.

I mean try using this

```
 $('form').submit(function(event) {
    var id = $('#tech_id').val().toString(16); // this converts to hexa
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'do_stuff',
     data: {id: id}, // this will be a String in hexa format.
     dataType: 'json',
     encode: true
})
```

Comment: I want to pass it as a string, not as an integer.

Comment: do you want String in decimal format only? actually .toString(16) returns a String in Hexa format.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    var id = ""+$('#tech_id').val();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'do_stuff',
     data: {id: id},
     dataType: 'json',
     encode: true
})
```

then at the time of query convert it into number or no need to convert it into number you can keep it as a string no problem

Answer (score 0):

use url_encode like this.

```
 $url = $host."/user/".$techid;
 $url=  url_encode($url);
```

and now use file get content may this help